# Illustrator: how to select all elements below a shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, selections

I'm trying to take a pre-drawn shape, move it into position over a number of smaller elements, and select all of the elements it covers so that I can change their colour.

It would be not unlike turning an image/logo into a mosiac, except the small elements aren't square, and they're pre-drawin into a (giant) array.

In the attached photo, I'm trying to fake a 'fair isle' effect without drawing it 'pixel by pixel' I'd like to take a shape (more complex than the circle) and select all of the knot elements in behind or covered by the shape.

[image]

Comment: I'm unaware of any "select below" functionality in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator cannot detect which elements of the pattern are covered by a shape. But you can use a [Clipping Mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html) to hide anything outside the shape:

- group all the knot elements. select one of these, go to 'Select → Same → Fill Color' and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
- make sure your shape sits on top of the group of knots
- select the group and the shape and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>